# Why the indexes not speeding up the query?

Tags: sql, indexing, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Status = 'N' AND Type is not null 
ORDER BY mytable.id
```

MyTable has 130 million rows.

I also created these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "MyTableIndex_1" ON MyTable (Status);
CREATE INDEX "MyTableIndex_2" ON MyTable (Type);
```

The ID column was already a clustered index.

Somehow the query is still very slow.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is the cardinality of `Status` and `Type`. Do you really need all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a multi column index

```
CREATE INDEX "MyTableIndex_StatusType" ON MyTable (Status, Type);
```

if that doesn't work then do some research on 'Covering Indexes'

Answer (score 0):

Type is not null ,  the index on this column might not help.

BTW, can you try update index statistics before the query?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).